# Arranging the fields in the required order

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There is a field output:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "text": "Test text1"
   "order": "1"
},
{
   "id": 2,
   "text": "Test text2"
   "order": "2"
},
{
   "id": 3,
   "text": "Test text3"
   "order": "3"
}
```

How to swap the fields according to how the user wants. That is, most likely you need to change the rows in the database itself. How can this be implemented using the REST API?

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "text": "Test text1"
   "order": "1"
},
{
   "id": 2,
   "text": "Test text3"
   "order": "3"
},
{
   "id": 3,
   "text": "Test text2"
   "order": "2"
}
```

Comment: Please ask the question in *English* or at [ru.SO].

Comment: Don't forget the title! That too must be in English. Also I don't really understand the question, do you want the data to be ordered in some specific manner? Just add a field for ordering (although it looks like you already have some `order` field)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat,  Yes, how approximately should a change occur in the database using code?